# ILGenerator - вызов static/instance методов

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте.
Чтобы много не объяснять - сразу приведу пример демонстрирующий проблему.

```
class Test
{
    void Test1()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test1");
    }
    static void Test2()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test2");
    }
}
```

...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Test tt = new Test();
        var dynMeth = new DynamicMethod("", typeof(void), new Type[]{}, typeof(Test));
        MethodInfo privateMethod = tt.GetType().GetMethod("Test2", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        ILGenerator gen = dynMeth.GetILGenerator();
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, privateMethod);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        dynMeth.Invoke(tt, null);
    }
```

Нужно тоже самое для метода "test1" и именно с DynamicMethod.
В голове уже все перепуталось, вот оно решение - перед носом, а ткнуть пальцем некому. 
Толковой литературы по данному вопросу маловато. Поэтому приветствуются любые  статьи\книги по данной тематике.

Comment: а в чем заключается проблема-то?

Comment: Не работает, в стеке должна присутствовать ссылка на экземпляр  Test. С созданием конструктора разобрался вот так ConstructorInfo ci = typeof(Test).GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, ci);
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, Method);
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

Comment: Так в чем вопрос, если разобрались уже?

Comment: Код выглядит рабочим...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
var dynMeth = new DynamicMethod("", typeof(void), new [] { typeof(Test) }, typeof(Test));
MethodInfo privateMethod = tt.GetType().GetMethod(
   "Test1", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

ILGenerator gen = dynMeth.GetILGenerator();
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, privateMethod);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

var result = (Action)dynMeth.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), tt);
result();
```

Вместо последних двух строчек можно делать так:

```
dynMeth.Invoke(null, new object[] { tt });
```

Первый параметр `Invoke` [игнорируется](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60yaa4yw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_0), поэтому стоит в обоих случаях (как для instance-, так и для статического метода) указывать `null`.

---

Отличие от вашего первого примера — ссылка на instance передаётся методу (скрытым) нулевым аргументом, поэтому тип этого аргумента нужно описывать при определении динамического метода.

Чтобы не гадать, какой именно ассемблерный код нужно писать, имеет смысл написать такой же или аналогичный метод сначала на C#, декомпилировать в IL при помощи любого декомпилятора (например, [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/)), и перенести опкоды в ваш код.

---

Литература:

- MSDN, [How to: Define and Execute Dynamic Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exczf7b9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- Dr. Dobb's, [Generating Code at Run Time With Reflection.Emit](http://www.drdobbs.com/generating-code-at-run-time-with-reflect/184416570)